# RSS feed captions

Tags: php, rss, magpie

How can I read the captions of a RSS feed from a given website? I have to use either Magpie or PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). Because an RSS feed is simply an XML file it should be fairly simple to parse it with simpleXML.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you use Simplepie http://simplepie.org/
Its very good documented and  easy to use

Comment: What do you understand under suitable?

Comment: I wrote the code which outputs everything as XHTML-code. Now how can I determine whether some text is a caption or not. Probably I'm doing something wrong as I started studying just today.